# angular 2/4 search suggestion not showing in textbox

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-forms

I am developing a drop down suggestion search box in angular 2/4.

**What I have done so far:**

When typing on text box and press search button the searched details are displayed.

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to show the searching, `‘as-you-type’` suggestion want to displayed (Like a dropdown search).

I tried severel other similiar questions, but the answers are not working for me.

I installed angular material and got some error in my packages.

**I want something like this**

[image]

I tried with the pipe but it did not work.

**Html**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div [innerHTML]="highlighted"></div>
        <input name="search" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" (keyup)="FetchItemDetailsSearch(searchcontent)" [(ngModel)]="searchcontent">                       
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-success ProductSearchBtn" type="button" 
                (click)='FetchItemDetailsSearch(searchcontent)'>
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span style="margin-left:10px;">Search</span>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>                  
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
FetchItemDetailsSearch(itemcodeordesc: string): void {

    this.pageIndex = 1;
    this.searchflag = 1;

    if (itemcodeordesc.length > 0)
        this.searchcontent = itemcodeordesc;
    else {
        itemcodeordesc = undefined
        this.searchcontent = itemcodeordesc;
    }
    this.prevScrollPosition = 0;

    this._enqService.FetchItemDetailsSearch(this.searchcontent, this.pageIndex).subscribe(itemsData => this.itemdetails = itemsData,
        error => {
            console.error(error);
            this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
        });
}
```

**I got like this( this is the problem, not showing the suggestion)**

[image]

I tried severel methods got from the web, but none of them give desired output.

This is my package .json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/core": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/http": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/router": "~4.3.4",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
```

I also try like [this](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples) but, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I just guessing that because your data is return inside the observable.
So in your html should have a pipe | async somewhere.

If this is not the problem then please provide me your `template` where you render `this.itemdetails`.(Suppose that your service actually return the values also)